# php time based background

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to make a site with a time based background,

- 06.00-12.00 it should show morning
- 12.00-18.00 it should show afternoon
- 18.00-00.00 it should show evening
- 00.00-06.00 it should show night

right now I made a code that should show all the cases but for some reason it does not show the time how and it only shows the morning how can I fix this? Does anyone have any tips for me?

```
<?php
      date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
      echo "It is now " . date("h:i");
      
    function getTime() {
    
    
        $time = date('H');
        $style = "";
    
        if ($time >= 6 && $time <= 12) {
            $style = $style . "morning";
            define("MORNING", "Goodmorning!");
        }
        elseif($time >= 12 && $time <= 18){
            $style = $style . "afternoon";
            define("AFTERNOON", "Goodafternoon!");
        }
        elseif($time >= 18 && $time <= 0){
            $style = $style . "evening";
            define("EVENING", "Goodevening!");
        }
        else {
            $style = $style . "night";
            define("NIGHT", "Goodnight!");
        }
    
        echo $style;
    }
    ?>
    

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
   <title>PHP time based page</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Time" class="<?php getTime(); ?>">
    <h1><?php echo MORNING; ?></h1>
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
    color: white;
}

#Time{
    margin-top: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.morning{
    background: url("images/morning.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    height: 700px;
}

.afternoon{
    background: url("images/afternoon.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    height: 700px;
}

.evening{
    background: url("images/evening.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    height: 700px;
}

.night{
    background: url("images/night.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    height: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Sure it shows morning, line `<h1><?php echo MORNING; ?></h1>` :-) In if-else statements define ONE variable/constant, `define('DAYTIME', 'Goodmorning');`, `define('DAYTIME', 'Good afternoon');`, etc., than in template `echo DAYTIME`.

Comment: Just one more notice: condition `elseif($time >= 18 && $time <= 0)` will be always false.

Comment: ah i see, so because i made different constants that thing didnt work

Comment: it should be elseif($time >= 18 && $time <= 6) then? and it the time now showing because of the images?

Comment: No, `$time` will never be higher than 18 and lower than 0 or 6. Basic math.

Comment: my math isnt that good, so it should be left out?

Comment: `elseif($time >= 18 || $time == 0)`

Comment: oh i get it, because it cant be lower it should be == instead of <=

Comment: fyi, you have multiple equal conditions `$time <= 12`, `elseif($time >= 12)` (same for 18) - remove the `=` from one of those conditions